# Mysql FullText Syntax Error #1215

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table

```
CREATE TABLE tag (
  name VARCHAR(294) NOT NULL,
  inserted_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  status INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
) Engine=innoDB;

CREATE TABLE item (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(294) NOT NULL,
  price INTEGER NOT NULL,
  discounted_price INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  unit VARCHAR(294) NOT NULL,
  additional_message TEXT NOT NULL,
  stock INTEGER NOT NULL,
  is_featured INTEGER NOT NULL,
  inserted_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  status INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=innoDB;

ALTER TABLE item ADD FULLTEXT(name, additional_message);

CREATE TABLE item_tag (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  item_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  tag_name VARCHAR(294) NOT NULL,
  inserted_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  status INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_name) REFERENCES tag(name),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item(id)
) Engine=innoDB;

ALTER TABLE item_tag ADD FULLTEXT(tag_name);
```

The first Alter Command works perfectly, but the second does not. It return #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Do you know why?, or better, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot have MySQL 5.5 does not support FullText and Foreign key constraint together on the same. You can create either of them to get it working.

Comment: So to use full text, i need to create a surrogates field ?, let say, column 'search_name' in item_tag table

Comment: @MarcelAng:- Indeed or else if there is an option then you can switch to 5.6 version